# How to open a modal with in a modal without closing parent modal | react-modal

Tags: reactjs, react-modal

I am using [React Modal Plugin](http://reactcommunity.org/react-modal/) to display the modals. I am trying to achieve to below scenario.

1. On button click a modal will open, inside the modal, i have another button, on click of this button, need to open another modal. but the first opened modal, should stay in the back. I didn't see any documentation regarding this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is already supported. Just nest the modal components. That is, inside the rendered content of the first modal, render another modal component. When you click the opening element of the second modal, it will appear in front of the first, while the first stays open in the background.

Comment: Some code demonstrating how to do this would be nice